# Taking values of objects from json

Tags: android, json

I am new in android.I need to take values from web service.Here i used json parsing.The out put Json format is given below. Here i need to take the value of objects .How i take the values of objects.please help me.

```
{
   "result":[
      [
         {
            "transaction date":"2013-12-19T10:44:45+0530",
            "earned points":"0",
            "amount":"15202",
            "transaction id":"8",
            "transaction type":1
         },
         {
            "transaction date":"2013-12-16T07:14:13+0530",
            "earned points":"11",
            "amount":"12121",
            "transaction id":"4",
            "transaction type":0
         }
      ]
   ]
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Is your code not working? What errors do you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to parse the json

```
{  // JSONObject node 
   "result":[ // JSONArray result
      [       // JSONArray node 
         {   // JSONObject node
```

To parse

```
 try
    {
    JSONObject jb = new JSONObject("My JSON");
     JSONArray jr = jb.getJSONArray("result"); 
     JSONArray jr1 = jr.getJSONArray(0);
     for(int i=0;i<jr1.length();i++)
     {
         JSONObject job = jr1.getJSONObject(i);
         Log.i("............",""+job.getString("transaction date"));
             String earnedpoints = job.getString("earned points"); 
             String amount = job.getString("amount");   
             String id = job.getString("transaction id"); 
             int type =  job.getString("transaction type");
     }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Log

```
01-03 04:49:09.940: I/............(1397): 2013-12-19T10:44:45+0530
01-03 04:49:09.940: I/............(1397): 2013-12-16T07:14:13+0530
```

Answer (score 0):

try this store this value of the variable

```
String transaction_date="";    
int epoints=0,amount=0,tid=0,ttype=0;
        try{
        JSONObject jObject= new JSONObject(output);
        JSONArray menuObject = new JSONArray(jObject.getString("result"));          
                       for (int i = 0; i<menuObject.length(); i++)
                                {
                            transition date=    menuObject.getJSONObject(i).getString("transaction date");
                            epoints=menuObject.getJSONObject(i).getInt("earned points");
                            amount=menuObject.getJSONObject(i).getInt("amount");
                            tid=menuObject.getJSONObject(i).getInt("transaction id");
                            ttype=menuObject.getJSONObject(i).getInt("transaction type");
                                }
            }catch(Exception e){
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use JSONObject and JSONArray.

```
JSONObject jsonObj= new JSONObject([your json string]);
JSONArray jsonArr = jsonObj.getJSONArray("result");

for (int i = 0; i < jsonArr.length(); i++) {
JSONObject current = jsonArr.getJSONObject(i);
String temp = current.getString([your key]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I put my answer as there are already 4 in line. However, all of them advise towards using manual parsing of the whole JSON, which is:

- quite cumbersome
- very difficult to maintain
- hard to understand

I, myself, am always using JSON parsing library if I have to parse more than a single field. I recommend using [GSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/). Add it to the class path. It is better if you define the element of the json array you want to parse as class (which probably you have done anyway):

```
public class Transaction {
  @SerializedName("transaction date")
  private Date transactionDate;
  @SerializedName("earned points")
  private String earnedPoints;
  private int amount;
  @SerializedName("transaction id")
  private int transactionId;
  @SerializedName("transaction type")
  private int transactionType;
  //optional getters / setters
}
```

Note that field names consisting of several words are not valid, that's why I use the `@SerializedName` annotation to ensure proper parsing.

Then lets assume you have the json in `String json`:

```
GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
// I think this is the date format you are using
gsonBuilder.setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ssZ");
Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
Transaction[] transactions = gson.fromJson(json, Transaction[].class);
```

And that's it. You have the date parsed immediately and objects ready to use.